# how to set private structure fields in a public property?

Tags: c#, properties, structure

I have a structure:

```
public struct ServiceDescription
        {
            string serviceDescriptionText;
            string serviceLogoRef;

            /// <summary>
            /// The position to print the service on the label.
            /// </summary>
            int servicePosition;

            /// <summary>
            /// Constructor
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="serviceDescriptionText"></param>
            /// <param name="serviceLogoRef"></param>
            /// <param name="servicePosition"></param>
            public ServiceDescription(string serviceDescriptionText, string serviceLogoRef,
                                        int servicePosition)
            {
                this.serviceDescriptionText = serviceDescriptionText;
                this.serviceLogoRef = serviceLogoRef;
                this.servicePosition = servicePosition;
            }
        }
```

and a property:

```
public string pServiceDescription
{
    get
    {
        return p_sServiceDescription;
    }
    // set private structure field 1
    // set private structure field 2
    // etc...
}
```

How do I set each of the private fields of the structure in the setters of my property?

Comment: Do you mean `set { p_sServiceDescription = value; }`?

Comment: Mutable structs are evil.  This type shouldn't be a struct in the first place, it meets none of the criteria for being a struct.

Comment: Well, I don't know, because how will that set the private string variables inside my structure?

Comment: @Servy if it was immutable, I would have no problem with it being a struct. There are scenarios where a group of associated data makes perfect sense as a struct.

Comment: @dotNetBlackBelt if the property is inside your struct it has access to the private fields, but I don't even see a `p_sServiceDescription` field in the first place.

Comment: @MarcGravell It doesn't appear to represent a single logical value.

Comment: Ah - so "mutable structures" is what I am after ??

Comment: private ServiceDescription p_sServiceDescription

sorry - forgot to add that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is usually a very bad idea to have mutable structs; mutable value-type semantics is *not* what people usually expect. You *can*, however, simply add a `set` that works like any other regular setter. It just isn't a very good idea:

```
public string Text
{
    get { return text; }
    set { text = value; } // this is a really bad idea on a struct
}
```

If it was me, that would be an immutable struct with `private readonly` fields and a constructor that sets all of them (and `get`-only properties), or a class - probably with automatically implemented properties, i.e.

```
public class ServiceDescription {
    public string Text {get;set;}
    //...
}
```

Comment: +1. Note that settable fields of struct is even worse for struct intended to be used as *property* on other types - as you can't really set it via `instance.StructField.Value = "newValue"` due to the fact properties returning *copy* of the struct.

Comment: Thanks for the advanced knowledge.